# VPN/Proxy server to bypass work proxy

Tags: vpn, proxy, bypass

Here is my dilema, I am at work and can not set up a VPN connection to my VPN account in the USA.  So what I would like to do is somehow have my "IE" at work connect to my home network and route any internet requests through my home PC to my VPN account, so I can access my USA Contents?

So what I was thinking and I am not sure if this will work, but set up a proxy server at home on my home computer, that then routes all requests to my VPN Tunnel to the USA.  Have my work computer use my home computer as the proxy and viola I have unrestricted internet access?  Does that sound feasable?

Thanks.

Comment: Knowing the OS' of the computers involved might help to answer your question.

Comment: It is feasible, but think about this -- if you can't set up a VPN connection maybe the system administrators at your place of work have put some restrictions and, how to put it nicely -- they won't appreciate if you bypass these restrictions.

Comment: Sorry at work we use XP SP3, at home I have Windows 7.  As for the restrictions stopping things well yes they do have some restrictions but for the most part it is to stop things like Facebook, imaging sites...etc.  I can connect via Logmein to my home computer so I know that there is no restriction there.

Comment: so you tried directly your USA VPN. Can you elaborate what settings you tried?

Answer (score 1):

1. get a cheap VPS account.  You can find tons of choices at lowendbox.com.  spotvps.com offers one for $15/year.
2. Tunnel your IE traffic over SSH using Putty.  Here's a guide I found on google: http://hidefinder.com/90/diy-socks5-vpn-putty.html

-You might need to run ssh over port 443 if your employer is blocking port 22

-This will only tunnel traffic for your browser.  To tunnel all traffic you can setup OpenVPN.  OpenVPN cannot be filtered since it uses standard protocols.  This would be a more complicated option.

The ssh/putty route is really easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Linux box at home, and can deal with the bit of hassle of setting it up (set up Java, etc.), [Adito, being renamed to OpenVPN ALS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openvpn-als/) is a Web-accessible SSL VPN relying on a Java applet to do port-forwarding based tunneling to your home network.

Once you get it set up it's very convenient.  It seems to have been on version 0.91 forever but works well enough for me.  I use it quite a bit.